# Rails Job to Merge Records With Similar Phone Numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, oop, activerecord

I have a Postgres database with tens of thousands of User records, each having a phone number. However, there are many duplicate Users with the same phone number, but one record might be missing the country code. For example:

`{name: "User1", phone: "1-123-456-7890"}`
`{name: "User1", phone: "123-456-7890"}`

Both these users are the same person, but one record has the country code, the other does not. I would want to merge these records, keeping the phone number with the country code. My goal is to create a Rails Job to find all similar matches based off the phone number. However, user's phone numbers vary in length depending on the country code (USA/Canada = +1, Argentina = +54). Since all phone numbers have a minimum length of 10 digits, I intended on querying by the LAST 10 digits of each phone number. If there are any matches, I would then merge these records.

I'm in the process of building the query, but am having some difficulty getting all matches. Here is the Active Job I have so far:

```
class MergeRecordsJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user)
    matches = User.where("phone LIKE ?", user[user.length * -1..-1])
    p "There are #{matches.count}"
  end
end
```

Am I headed in the right direction with this? I can call this Job in my terminal with a sample size of about 1,000 records that I know contains duplicates. Once these duplicates are found, how do you suggest I go about merging them?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are all the numbers stored with the EXACT same format? i.e. ###-###-####? If there is any question about format, then you probably want to use a regexp for this.

Comment: Also "how to go about merging them" is a huge question with no context. Are you OK with deleting one of the duplicate records? Are there other records in other tables that point towards the user_id you are deleting? That question sounds like something I'd get paid a contractor fee to solve. LOL But in its simplest form you'd have to find every instance of user_id in other tables and update that to the id of the record you are keeping.

Comment: And as far as the searching goes: you are asking the DB for duplicate records that aren't actually duplicates, i.e. the phone numbers are different. Do you want to define if they are duplicate or not based on the `name` or the last 10 digits of the phone number. Name is trivial, last ten digits is almost trivial IF they all follow the same format other than the leading country code. If some numbers are 203-555-1212 and others are (203)555-1212 it becomes a bit more involved. Not an insurmountable problem but now you are in "fuzzy searching".

Comment: @Beartech Thanks for the reply. I have all phone numbers already saved in a formatted column, where I removed all non-numeric characters. So all of these phone number strings only contain digits (e.g. "1234567890", "11234567890"). I see what you mean about finding every instance of user_id in other tables. I thought finding duplicates by phone number, specifically the last 10 digits of the phone number would give me the best results (as this removes any country codes). I want to delete duplicate records, but sounds like this may break some associations if other table's user_ids aren't updated?

Comment: Yes. But not too hard. Are there other tables where duplicate user_ids would be a problem? i.e. a table where each user can only have one of the related items in that table? `has_one` in any of your models would point you in that direction. Also any unique constraints in models OR in the DB would help uncover that. There are delete strategies like: update ALL the duplicate user accounts to have all the same info (an all the same related records if not uniq constrained) then just delete any (with cascading delete on other records) other than the first one of the duplicates. thus no loss of data

Comment: You can at least query to know how many duplicates you have and how extensive the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find your duplicates you should be able to do this:

```
dup_accts = User.group('RIGHT(phone, 10)').having("count(RIGHT(phone, 10)) > 1").count
```

assuming "phone" is the name of the column where your phone numbers are stored. This matches on the right 10 digits so it will ignore country codes. You will get a hash with any duplicate numbers and the count of how many duplicates there are. i.e. `2035551212 => 3`. You then can loop through each duplicate number to find the actual users that are duplicated.

```
User.where('RIGHT(phone, 10) = ?', 2035551212)
```

This returns an array of the duplicate users records...

```
=> [#<User:0x00007f7bd4ab5c50
    id: 13625,
    phone: '12035551212'
    ...>,

   #<User:0x00007f7bd4ab5ac0
    id: 13645,
    phone: '2035551212'
    ...>]
```

Now you just have to figure out how you want to deal with them. I would recommend a job so it doesn't kill your server resources. I'd also process one at a time rather than trying to load them all into memory. Depending on how big the `dup_accts` comes back, you can either grab that, then iterate over them by phone number. Or if it's huge you can grab them in slices like...

```
 dup_accts.each_slice(1000) do |dup_chunk|
   dup_chunk.each do |k,v|   #you only really need the key but it's a hash
     User.where('RIGHT(phone, 10) = ?', k)
       #returns an array of user records as noted above.
       #this is where you do your duplicate removal procedure, whatever
       #you determine that to be. 
   end
 end
```

If the phone number is the determining factor on who a user is (i.e. not email address or username) then you could try to notify them via phone or email that they have duplicate accounts. But if you had two distinct users who put in the same number in two formats, accidentally or on purpose, you have a bigger issue. If you have no problem deleting the duplicates, then you just need to come up with a procedure for that to attach any child records to the record you are keeping. But this answer at least gets you the list of duplicate phone numbers and the associated account.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is super helpful. I can definitely implement this and give it a try. I appreciate your help!!!